# Is "so" considered informal?

Tags: conjunctions

Is "so" considered informal. and not suitable for formal writing, such as writings for application to graduate schools?

For example,

> My experiences are non-traditional, so I had wondered what I could bring for my application. Now, my answer is ...

alternatively,

> My experiences are non-traditional. Therefore I had wondered what I could bring for my application. Now, my answer is ...

What would you write, if it were you? Thanks!

By the way, is "bring ... for my application" correct?

Comment: I don't like the second one at all. The first sentence seems too short, giving the text a "choppy" feel. Another alternative would be: _Because my experiences are non-traditional, I wondered what I could bring for my application._

Comment: @J.R.: I started my statement of purpose with the quote. I have changed it to "My experiences are non-traditional. Therefore, my friend asked me what I could bring for my application. Now, my answer is ...". I guess using "I had wondered" might make people more doubt about my resolution?

Comment: @Tim: The "I had wondered" is doubtful indeed, doesn't make sense if I might say. Take a look at my answer below.

Comment: By "bring" do you mean _bring something with you_, to a face-to-face interview? Most applications to graduate school are done with letters and electronic forms, which is why I was confused by "bring." But I'm starting to understand it now, based on your [other comment](http://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/15141/is-so-considered-informal/15143#comment27306_15143) below.

Comment: @J.R.: I mean bring something about me to "the table" for my application.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your example, "so" is not informal. It's a perfectly good word.

"So" may be informal in other contexts. For example, "So, what do you think?" where it is probably just a filler word (depending on context).

Comment: Thanks! Do you like the first one with "so", or the second one with "therefore"? A side question, which one do you think is better, "I had wondered" or "I have wondered"?

Comment: I don't think either is really "better". "Therefore" is longer and therefore sounds a little more formal, perhaps.

Comment: "I had wondered" is past perfect while "I have wondered" is present perfect. That is, "I had wondered" means that you wondered at some specific time in the past, but you are not wondering now. "I have wondered" means you wondered in the past and you still wonder now. As I think in context your last sentence indicates that you now believe you have the solution, the wondering is over, so "I had wondered" appears to be what you mean.

Answer (score 3):

It's exactly as written in Jay's answer. Not only that the *so* is **not** informal, but also is written perfectly correctly.

What bothers me is the *therefore*. It's indeed formal, but it's not written correctly.

You should write it like this:

> My experiences are non-traditional. **Therefore,** I **am wondering what to do** about/with my application. Now, my answer is ...

See, I put a comma (`,`) there (after the word *therefore*). To write a consequence sentence after the cause sentence, you write the word connecting them along with a comma.

Besides, you **are** wondering *at the moment*, so using a past perfect tense is not a good idea. Since it'll mean that you **did** wonder, **not** anymore. [This counts only if I get your meaning correctly, that you're still confused about what to do with the application.]

The last thing is, the *bring for my application* just seems a bit weird and uncommon to me. Cause the verb *bring* has a direct object. Therefore, it cannot be followed by *for* (should be followed by a noun). Besides, you can't *bring* anything if it's about an application. Cause what you bring is the application itself. Maybe you wanted to say:

> - *what to do about the application*, or
> - *what to put on the application* (like what J.R.'s comment said), or
> - *what to use for the application*.

Unless, you meant you're confused *what application to bring.*

On the other side, I prefer *therefore*, cause it'll make the sentences look pretty well arranged. [What you were confused might not be the informality, but the "look" of the sentences]

This is a better formed sentence suggested by Damkerng T.:

> *I am well aware that my experiences are non-traditional at best; therefore, I am wondering which experiences of mine are worth mentioning in my application ...*

Comment: I agree about "bring for my application" – it sounds odd. I wonder if the O.P. means "what to **put on** my application."

Comment: Maybe, but he has not responded to this answer yet. So we don't know what he actually wants to say.

Comment: @J.R. and Safira: "I would like to bring some characteristics of mine (such as curiosity, knowledge, experiences, etc) to the table for my application." Does that still not make sense? What would you say if it were you?

Comment: Hold on, what kind of application do you mean? Is that some software or what? It still sounds weird to bring your characteristics. It could be like *show, use,* or something similar, not *bring*. It's not common.

Comment: graduate school application.

Comment: @Tim Reading all the answers and comments, I think this should be close enough: *"I am well aware that my experiences are non-traditional at best; therefore, I am wondering which experiences of mine are worth mentioning in my application ..."*

Comment: Tim: Damkerng's recommendation is nice. @DamkerngT.: +1. May I adopt your comment to edit the answer?

Comment: @Safira Of course! I'm glad that it's useful. :)

Comment: This is a wording I came up with: _"My experiences are non-traditional, so I had wondered what I **might include on** my application."_ Truthfully, though, I like the suggestion provided by @Damkerng even better.

Comment: @DamkerngT. & J.R.: Thanks! Do you feel the "wondering" part may cause the admission committee to doubt my resolution? Does "at best" mean "barely"? How about "Although my experiences are non-traditional, in my application, I would like to present my love for certain subject,  curiosity, knowledge, experience, perseverance, etc"?

Comment: @Tim: I think "present my love" is a step in the wrong direction. _"Although my experiences are non-traditional, my passion for the subject, my curiosity and perseverance, and my experience are **noteworthy and relevant**."_ As a side note, I don't think that a single word (like "so" or "wondering") will make or break your application package.

Comment: @Tim Perhaps I misunderstand a little, because I thought the sentence was for an inquiry about your application, not for the application itself. If you are writing your application, it might be better to express your experiences right away, imho. For example, *"Although I am well aware that my experiences are non-traditional, I would like to present my commitment to these certain subjects ..."*

Comment: @J.R. Thanks! I think your expression is a good one. My non-traditional experience is featured by some lesson. If I hope to mention I have learned from my past lesson, how will you include it in your sentence? For example,  "Although my experiences are non-traditional, my passion for the subject, my curiosity and perseverance, and my experience are noteworthy and relevant, and I have learned from my past lesson"?

Comment: @J.R. By the way why "present my love" is a step in the wrong direction? Why do you use passion instead of love?

Comment: @Tim - My biggest problem was with "present"; that verb didn't sound natural in your sentence. As for _love_ vs. _passion_, try looking [here](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/american/passion) and pay particular attention to Definitions 3 and 3a. A research physicist may **love** chocolate ice cream, but he is **passionate** about physics – not the other way around. Another good word choice might be _enthusiasm_. As for "learned from past lesson," that can be referred to as "life experiences."